# Complete list of Bootstrap Classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a complete list of the classes bootstrap uses anywhere?  I keep breaking bootstrap things when I make my own **independent of bootstrap** classes, so I'd like to eliminate that overlap

Comment: Take a look here [https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145](https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145)

Comment: submit it as an answer and i'll accept! thanks

Comment: just name space your custom css to avoid conflicts. so .widget becomes .mycustom-widget or whatever you want to use

Comment: i shouldn't have to do that though, itd make more sense for bootstrap to be doing that, in case multiple bootstrap-like entities conflict.  but it is a valid way to solve this, thanks

Comment: Agreed.  Why is it that Bootstrap didn't include name spaces on their classes?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here the list of classes from boostrap.min.css https://gist.github.com/geksilla/6543145

Comment: Here is a sortable table of classes for Bootstrap 4 https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-4-classes-list-reference-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @BuDen which version is it for? It doesn't include for example `.table-striped` of BS3

Answer (score 36):

Similar to the link above, except this link actually is a complete list of Boostrap 3 classes (656 unique classes) along with code on how you can easily generate your own complete list any time, for any frontend framework css file:

https://gist.github.com/mrcybermac/9175466

Comment: More helpful than the accepted answer, because it's alphabetically sorted.

Comment: ...and it includes probably all classes, for example `.table-striped`

Answer (score 19):

Someone might be looking for a list of Bootstrap 3 CSS classes with a simple description - I've written one as I couldn't find any, hope it helps.

[List of Bootstrap 3 CSS classes with description](http://tomasjanecek.cz/en/clanky/post/list-of-bootstrap-3-css-classes-with-description)

Comment: thanks for that, even better now that corp proxy blocks access to github xD

Answer (score 9):

**Blog sub domain have been removed**

Archive link: [a complete reference library of bootstrap classes](https://web.archive.org/web/20131121140101/http://blog.seosemanticxhtml.com/a-complete-reference-library-of-bootstrap-classes/)

Comment: Nice find, very helpful descriptions and links

Comment: Blog subdomain seems to have been removed (not in DNS at all). Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20131121140101/http://blog.seosemanticxhtml.com/a-complete-reference-library-of-bootstrap-classes/

Comment: As u have updated answer, u should remove broken link from ur answer. So that people won't visit broken link.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a Bootstrap CSS classes desk reference pdf and a sortable table with descriptions to help sort through the list. You can find it here.

**Version 4 update:** https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-4-css-classes-index/

https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-3-css-classes-index/

[image: Bootstrap 3 Classes Cheat Sheet]

Comment: I use it often and i like how the image show on hover. Thanks

Comment: The quick-search feature is nice, but the list is not complete, for example doesn't include `.table-striped`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @ellockie the that class has been added.

Answer (score 2):

I used nodejs to accomplish this, at https://gist.github.com/moorage/9965839